# Is every smooth atlas for a manifold with boundary contained in a unique maximal smooth atlas?

Tags: solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm wondering if the following proposition (from Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*) also applies to smooth manifolds **with boundary**:

[image]

---

**Definition:** a map from an arbitrary subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ is said to be ***smooth*** if in a neighborhood of each point of $A$ it admits an extension to a smooth map defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

It seems to me that proposition **1.17** *does apply* to manifolds with boundary, and the proof is essentially the same (picture below), but using the fact that a composition of smooth maps (in the 'general sense' as defined above) is smooth, which can be proven as follows:

**Theorem:** a composition of smooth maps is smooth i.e. given the arbitrary (non-empty) subsets $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$, and the smooth maps $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $g:B\to\mathbb{R}^p$, then $(g\circ f):A\cap f^{-1}(B)\to\mathbb{R}^p$ is smooth.

*Proof:* choose $p\in A\cap f^{-1}(B)$. There are (open) neighborhoods $U$ of $p$ and $V$ of $f(p)$ and smooth (in the ordinary sense) maps $F:U\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $G:V\to\mathbb{R}^p$ that agree with $f$ and $g$ on $A$ and $B$ respectively. Since $F$ is smooth it is also continuous, and thus $F^{-1}(V)$ is open. Therefore $U\cap F^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset containing $p$ where $(G\circ F)$ is smooth (in the ordinary sense) and agrees with $(g\circ f)$ on $A\cap f^{-1}(B)$.

---

[image]

---

**Am I correct that the above argument generalizes naturally to manifolds with boundary?**

Comment: The existence of maximal atlases follows, as you say, in the same way that it does for manifolds without boundary. In fact the same holds for manifolds with corners (which is what you are led to if you have to consider products of manifolds with boundaries).